# Share a shared folder in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, shared-folders

Somebody has shared a folder for me which I've read access only, how can I share it for someone in windows 7? I've tried to share it but there is no option for it!

tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been given read access to the share, which is not the same as having access to the folder the share is actually pointing too.

I presume the folder is on this persons machine or on a file server, you would need to directly edit the sharing permissions, not something you can do with your read access permissions and view of the folder.

**e.g**

If the share is currently pointing too `\\HPCOMPUTER\Finance` you would need to access `HPCOMPUTER` and edit the share permissions on the `Finance` folder.